# Thousands of parked thread

Tags: tomcat, apache-tomee

I notice my application have thousands of these threads, just wondering what is the source of these and how to get rid of these? These do not seem to pose any issue so far but it does not look good to see them there like this. Any useful information is appreciated. This is a java application running in tomcat.

```
"org.apache.openejb.pool.scheduler.124" daemon prio=5 tid=2599 TIMED_WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
       Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject#1320
       Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$Node#3514
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
       Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock#5616
       Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue#458
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
       Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#458
       Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker#457
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's completely dependent on your codebase. If your app creates or uses a bunch of `@Schedule` annotations or a bunch of calls to `TimerService` this is expected and these are mainly harmless; they use a teeny bit of memory but that's probably not worth losing sleep over.

If your app isn't using timers in any form that'd be pretty interesting. I would post a reproducible example as well the version of Java and TomEE you are using.

Comment: Application do not use any of these. This is old TomEE 1.7 and java 1.8. I am noticing that these threads are added as soon as applications are deployed. So, for example, if you deploy 4 applications lets say there are 600 such threads and if you deploy 10 there may be 1200 and so on. I have not found any documentation on what is the basis behind spawning these threads, however its obvious these are crated as soon as applications are deployed based on some hidden formula. Any insights or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the threads themselves are a problem, but TomEE 1.7 is pretty old and could have a lot of CVEs in it.